# How can I avoid this TypeError when creating a new column for my dataframe which multiplies the values in another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, typeerror

I am trying to add a column which converts bitcoin values to GBP to my dataframe in pyspark however when I run the code I get a Type Error. I have tried to create a variable with the same Type as the column to avoid this but I am unable to resolve the error.

```
bc_value = DecimalType("4000")
df_j2 = df_j2.withColumn("value",df_j2["value"].cast(DecimalType()))
df_group = df_j2.groupBy("pubkey").sum("value")
df_final = df_group.sort(df_group["sum(value)"].desc()).limit(10)
df_with_pound = df_final.withColumn("pound", col(bc_value*("value")
df_with_pound.show()
```

Here is the error shown on screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code, including how decimal columns are defined and how columns are used. You can try the code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

bc_value = lit(4000).cast(DecimalType())
df_with_pound = df_final.withColumn("pound", col("value") * bc_value)
```